# Does Google Analytics emit an event when they are set up?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, callback, shopify

Some of our customers want to have their Google Analytics id reported to them.  It's not hard to get it.

`ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');`

There is also a queued syntax, so that an operation is done when GA is set up.

But don't want to send a GA event when GA is ready.  I want to ask GA a question when it is ready.

Perhaps there is some way to say to GA "When you're ready, run this function I'm passing you."

Alternatively, does GA emit a custom event when it is ready?

Currently, my customer is calling my code when window emits the load event.  But even then, a fraction of the time ga isn't defined.  If you wait a few seconds, it's defined.  Perhaps some weird cdn system.  Anyway, I need a reliable way of determine when GA is ready.

---

(I wasn't able to make formatting in the comments cooperate, so I changed my question to respond to Feathercrown.)

That sounds great!  The only problem is that ga isn't defined yet.  Here is a sample of the error message I send myself.

    `"type": "Page View",
    "data": {
        "error": {
            "message": "ga.getAll is not a function. (In 'ga.getAll()', 'ga.getAll' is undefined)",
            "message2": "window.GoogleAnalyticsObject = ga",
            "message3": "typeof ga is not Object"
        }
    },`

Maybe that _gxx something symbol is already available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `ga()` with just a function can be used as a callback (`ga(readyCallback)`), as the function will only be run "when the analytics.js library is loaded and ready."

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference):

> Invoking the ga() command queue function by passing it a function will
>   schedule the passed function for execution at the next point in the
>   queue.
>
> Since commands are only executed after the analytics.js library is
>   fully loaded, the most common reason to pass the command queue a
>   function is as a callback for when the analytics.js library is loaded
>   and ready.

Therefore, you could try:

```
ga(function(){var clientId = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');});
```

or something similar.

Comment: (Feathercrown, see earlier response in the bottom of the answer.)  Looking at that javascript snippet in the documentation that you reference, it looks as though ga should be defined right away.  However, it is not.  Something funky my customer is doing at this website?

Comment: I guess I'm a little bit amazed that waiting until the 'load' event on the window isn't long enough.  At least for the window.ga symbol to be defined.  But I suppose they could put the GA initialization code on a setTimeout, or anything, and I wouldn't know.

Comment: I'm not sure it'll help the next guy, but we solved our problem.  Our customer is using Shopify.  Shopify has a place to put in "the Google Analytics snippet."  And it has a place to put code that should immediately follow the GA snippet.  At that place we put code to emit a custom event.  Then elsewhere in the code we listened for that event, and did what we needed to do.  Put a function in the ga queue, just as Feathercrown described.  Very Shopify-specific, but maybe it'll help somebody.

Comment: Yay, it worked! PS-- putting the <script> tag further up the document could help load it faster or maybe delay document.onload until the script is loaded, just a thought.